# Loop youtube clip on flash As3

Tags: actionscript-3, api, flash

I have this code which playing youtube movie in flash As3.
it working fine, but i can't make that movie will play again on ending.
any ideas?

here the code:

```
  Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");

var my_player:Object;


var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
my_loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&loop=1;")); 
my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);

function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void{
addChild(my_loader);
my_player = my_loader.content;

my_player.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);


} 

function onPlayerReady(e:Event):void{
my_player.setSize(300,300);
my_player.loadVideoById("indux8D-SoA&loop=1;",0);
my_player.mute();

}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `"onStateChange"` event listener for your `my_player` object.
And check when it pass `0` or `YT.PlayerState.ENDED`.

```
my_player.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);

function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
    if(Object(event).data==0){
    //reload, restart, rewind and so on code here;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could load youtube playlist with one video using `getPlaylist()`and use
`setLoop` method to loop playback of this "list"

```
my_player.setLoop(true);
```

Comment: thank you! 
can you show me how restart the movie again? what should exactly i write  under: if(Object(event).data==0){

thanks again

Comment: you could just reload video using
`my_player.loadVideoById("indux8D-SoA&loop=1;",0);`

Comment: First of all check if onPlayerStateChange event catched. Put some `trace("onPlayerStateChange");`inside
`function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {...}`
After that check result of `Object(event).data==0` operation in trace too.

Comment: Oh. I found mistake in code i provided - the name of function in `addEventListener` didn't match with defined one. Fixed now. My apologies.